# Is there a simple way to automatically test remote JMX URLs?

Tags: java, monitoring, jmx, automated-tests

I'm having a painful afternoon trying to configure a server to provide remote JMX access.  The simplest tool I've found to connect to a JMX server is jconsole, but it doesn't seem a great tool when trying to repeatedly access multiple URLs.

Is there a simple way, preferably from the command line, to check if a particular URL points to a valid JMX server?  E.g.

```
jmxTest service:jmx:rmi://192.168.0.101:1099/jndi/rmi://192.168.0.101:1099/jmxrmi
```

returning status 0 for a working server, and 1 for a non-working one

## Edit

I tried the following, but it seems to work even when the first half of the JMX URL points to a non-existent IP:

```
JMXServiceURL url = new JMXServiceURL(urlAsString);
JMXConnector jmxc = JMXConnectorFactory.connect(url, null);

MBeanServerConnection mbsc = jmxc.getMBeanServerConnection();
mbsc.getDomains();
```

Comment: If you feel JConsole as painful, I think other alternative is write a simple class and change url whenever you need to test new one.

Answer (score -1):

There are many tools that support jmx access. You can write your simple main class, make it accept params, or a config file, and it can do the check for you.

Or you can use a tool that is more suited for that, for example [JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/). Take a look at that:
http://wiki.apache.org/jmeter/JmxTestPlan

It also has a gui so you don't get xml crazy.

Comment: Thanks.  Sounds like it might be a little heavyweight for my current needs, but will take a look.